# Trying to delete permissions returns HTTP 403 - Operation not allowed

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

When trying to do a DELETE operation using this request `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/permissions/{perm-id}`, the Microsoft Graph has started returning an `HTTP 403` with this body:

```
{
    code: "notAllowed"
    innerError: {request-id: "6f8821bc-bb2a-46ba-89c8-99238765e27f", date: "2019-04-19T09:48:04"}
    message: "Operation not allowed"
}
```

This is extremely critical since we no longer have a way to remove permissions that we have added to a folder in a SharePoint site. We see that this problem is now affecting more and more tenants. Microsoft support has not been very helpful so far so I don't know where to take this. I think the problem is caused as a side-effect of work on the permission model in SharePoint/Microsoft Teams.

The strange thing is that it works when adding the new preview permissions scope `Sites.FullControl.All` while `Files.ReadWrite.All` or `Group.ReadWrite.All` does not work

Comment: The strange thing is that it works when adding the new preview permissions scope Sites.FullControl.All while Files.ReadWrite.All or Group.ReadWrite.All does not work

Comment: It seems we are seeing more and more 403 scenarios in the graph @marc-lafleur. Seems there are some issues with the required permission scopes, like in this case where Sites.FullControl.All is suddenly required to delete a permission on a folder in an Offic3 365 Group SharePoint site.

Answer (score 1):

this was definitely a bug and we've tracked down the cause and disabled the problematic code. In the future I'd recommend creating issues over at https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues for regressions in the OneDrive and SharePoint APIs as there are lot more eyes on it and there'll definitely be better traction.